# Redirect to an action with parameter and model binder doesn't work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-binding

Here is my codes. When I redirect response to an action, then model binder doesn't work.

Can anybody help me ?

```
public void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
{
  var action = filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"];
  var controller = filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"];
  var values = filterContext.RouteData.Values;
  var exceptionMessage = filterContext.Exception.Message;
  var exception = filterContext.Exception;

  filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
  ExceptionInfo ExceptionInfo = new ExceptionInfo();
  ExceptionInfo.ActionName = action.ToString();
  ExceptionInfo.ControllerName = controller.ToString();
  ExceptionInfo.ExceptionMessage = exceptionMessage;

  filterContext.HttpContext.Response.RedirectToRoute(new
  {
    action = "Error",
    controller = "Home",
    ExceptionInfo = ExceptionInfo
  });
}

public ActionResult Error(ExceptionInfo ExceptionInfo)
{
  return View(ExceptionInfo);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace your code with the following:

```
public void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
{
  var action = filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"];
  var controller = filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"];
  var values = filterContext.RouteData.Values;
  var exceptionMessage = filterContext.Exception.Message;
  var exception = filterContext.Exception;

  filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
  ExceptionInfo ExceptionInfo = new ExceptionInfo();
  ExceptionInfo.ActionName = action.ToString();
  ExceptionInfo.ControllerName = controller.ToString();
  ExceptionInfo.ExceptionMessage = exceptionMessage;

  filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new { 
    action = "Error", 
    controller = "Home", 
    exceptionInfo = ExceptionInfo
  }));
}

public ActionResult Error(ExceptionInfo exceptionInfo)
{
  return View(exceptionInfo);
}
```

Comment: What happens exactly?

Comment: the same result i got, null :( but if i redirect it with parameter by parameter woks

Comment: What do you mean if you redirect with parameter?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [Controller.RedirectToAction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470594%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) instead. There are lots of overloads of it that should enable you to re-route to the Controller/Action you require, with any parameters that are pertinent.